# WPF Composite Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to create a reusable UserControl in WPF that has a Label and a TextBox.  I want to add properties to my UserControl to bubble up the Text fields of both child controls up to the parent for easy binding.  I read that I need to a little bit of hocus pocus by adding owners to DependencyProperties.  Here is my code now.  It seems close but not quite right.  Any ideas?

Here is the Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MAAD.AircraftExit.Visual.LabelTextBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="20" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" TextAlignment="Right" Width="122" />
        <TextBlock Text=": " DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class LabelTextBox : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(LabelTextBox));
    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(LabelTextBox));
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelTextBox.TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public LabelTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ClearValue(HeightProperty);
        ClearValue(WidthProperty);
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is the final working code.  I switched over to relative source binding.

Comment: I tried the same thing at first as well assuming that thats what the owner concept was all about. Unfortunately I ran into the same problems and ended up resorting to using binding as well. Also my non-dependency properties have a different custom solution for propagating property change notifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Binding is really the way to go:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="testapp.LabelTextBox "
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="This">
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" TextAlignment="Right" Width="70" Name="label" Text="{Binding Label, ElementName=This}"  />
    <TextBlock Text=": " DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <TextBox Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=This}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
    public partial class LabelTextBox : UserControl
{
    public LabelTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label = "Label";
        Text = "Text";
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(LabelTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(LabelPropertyChangedCallback));
    private static void LabelPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject controlInstance, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
    }
    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(LabelTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TextPropertyChangedCallback));
    private static void TextPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject controlInstance, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelTextBox.TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I get this output when I try to use it:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=This'. BindingExpression:Path=Label; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out.  You defined This as the name of the control.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into exactly why your implementation isn't working, but I don't really understand why you're doing it that way. Why not just define the dependency properties you need on the UserControl and then bind to them?

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty = ...;
```

And then in your XAML:

```
<Label Content="{Binding LabelText}"/>
```